# Android broadcastReceiver on receive method

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I send data from one activity to another one but when I receive that data in my 2nd acitivity I cannot use that data for further purposes. But when I use that data for displaying TOAST message everything works well. I want when I send data from activity to another and open that activity that activity will show bottomsheet and in other cases do not show  . For example:

```
public BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            busNumber = intent.getStringExtra("busNumber");

            switch (busNumber) {
                case "1":
                    mMap.clear();
                    busNo_1();
                    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(140);
                    break;

                case "9":
                    mMap.clear();
                    busNo_9();
                    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(140);
                    break;

                default:
                    mMap.clear();
                    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
            }

        }
    };
```

It is the first time when I used broadcast receiver. I tried sending with intents and interfaces but it did not work.

And this is my adapter from where I send the data:

```
holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String busNumber = holder.busesNumber.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
                //            intent.putExtra("quantity",Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString()));
                intent.putExtra("busNumber",busNumber);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mCtx).sendBroadcast(intent);

                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(mCtx, MapActivity.class);
                mCtx.startActivity(mapIntent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot use data for further purposes"? In which case bottomsheet don not show? Can you share the specific code where you are facing the issue?

Comment: I have shared the code

Comment: my switch statement doesnt  work

Comment: if busnumber which I get from first activity is equal to "1" it will show bottomsheet with information related to 1 and so on

Comment: @Rick Sanchez,  in other cases when I used that switch statement everything worked good for example if user selects "1" from textview it shows me bottom sheet

Comment: You mentioned the cases in which the switch statement works but can you be specific about in which case it **doesn't work**?

Comment: @Rick Sanchezin all cases it doesn't work my switch statement doesn't work

Comment: @RickSanchez  I have never used broadcastreceiver so I do not know how to work with onReceive method

Comment: can you also post your activity, manifest file code or wherever you are registering for the broadcast receiver.

Comment: @RickSanchez I edited my question and added extra info

Comment: I tried to TOAST with the data I received from activity and it worked

Comment: but switch statement with that data did not work

Comment: maybe I could give you full source code??

Comment: Can you check your java version? is it below Java 7?

Comment: No my java version is 8

Comment: Actually please share other parts of your code. Especially where you are registering and sending the broadcast.

Comment: everything with broadcast I have shared with you

Comment: The switch statement looks good to me. Can you try printing the bus number before the `switch` statement and in each of the `case` statement.

Comment: I tried printing and it prints according to switch statement

Comment: But it does not show my bottomsheet

Comment: in other methods where I show my bottomsheet it works but when want to show it in broadcast receiver method it does not show